# Javascript random color "ball" not working properly

Tags: javascript

I have this project I am working on, and need to have this "ball" be a random color from the start-up. I can generate the random color, however the ball is continuously generating new colors throughout it's course down the screen. I only need each ball to be one random color. Help?! I am only an introductory student so I don't know much yet! Here is my code currently:

```
 var context;
 var x = Math.floor(450 * Math.random() + 1);
 var y = 0;
 var dx = 0;
 var dy = 2;
 var xx = 200;

 function startGame() {
     context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
     setInterval('drawEverything()', 50);
 }

 function drawEverything() {
     drawCircle();
     drawRectangle();
 }

 function drawCircle() {
     context.clearRect(0, 0, 450, 300);
     context.beginPath();
     context.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
     context.closePath();
     context.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
     context.fill();

     x += dx;
     y += dy;

 }

 function getRandomColor() {
     var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
     var color = '#';
     for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
     }
     return color;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried storing the colour in a variable defined outside the functions, the way you do with `x` and `y`? Then set the colour once from inside the `startGame()` function.

Comment: @nnnnnn is right. Because your "drawEverything()" is executed in intervals of 50, the ball will be rendered *with a new color* every time, as "drawEverything()" generates a new ball with a new color. Store the color in a variable outside of the function, then it will stay constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myRanColor =  getRandomColor();
function drawCircle()
{   
context.clearRect(0,0,450,300); 
context.beginPath(); 
context.arc(x,y,10,0,Math.PI*2);
context.closePath();
context.fillStyle=myRanColor;
context.fill(); 

x+=dx; 
y+=dy; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to make a circle object. You set the colour of the object when you first create it, and that never changes. And you update the position of the circle every time you draw it. This way you can have multiple circle objects, each with a different random colour. Here is my attempt with two circles (untested, so treat with caution!).

```
var circle1;
var circle2;

function getRandomColor () {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function Circle() {
    this.context = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    this.color = getRandomColor();
    this.x = Math.floor(450 * Math.random() + 1); 
    this.y = 0; 
    this.dx = 0; 
    this.dy = 2; 
    this.xx = 200; 
}

function Circle.prototype.draw () {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, 450, 300); 
    this.context.beginPath(); 
    this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
    this.context.closePath();
    this.context.fillStyle = this.color; 
    this.context.fill();

    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
}

function drawEverything()
{
    circle1.draw();
    circle2.draw();
}

function startGame()
{
    circle1 = new Circle();
    circle2 = new Circle();
    setInterval(drawEverything,50);
}
```

Here `new Circle()` creates a new circle object, and is only called once for each circle, in the `startGame` function. Each circle is drawn using its `draw` method, which is called continuously for both circles in the `drawEverything` function. The `prototype` in the draw method definition means that we can share the code for the different circles, but the circles themselves can have different values (the `this` in the Circle function and the draw method refers to the current circle object). See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS) for an introduction to object orientation in JavaScript.